# Query not working properly(syntax issue may be)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to remove all non numeric characters from my columns, I have a query inside my procedure but it is not completely working. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE NMS_DATA SET ALIAS=REPLACE(ALIAS,'[^0-9]','') WHERE ALIAS !='--';
```

Non numeric characters are still there after query is fired from the procedure.

Comment: Your search pattern is a regular expression but you are not using the regex version of `replace()`, which [`regexp_replace (link to docs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is **`REGEXP_REPLACE`** you need, not `REPLACE` (at least, according to code you wrote).

For example:

```
SQL> with nms_data (alias) as
  2    (select 'abc993' from dual union all
  3     select '332#$'  from dual union all
  4     select '--'     from dual union all
  5     select 'xyz'    from dual union all
  6     select '1234'   from dual union all
  7     select '$#%'    from dual
  8    )
  9  select alias,
 10         regexp_replace(alias, '[^0-9]', '') result
 11  from nms_data
 12  where alias <> '--';

ALIAS  RESULT
------ --------------------
abc993 993
332#$  332
xyz
1234   1234
$#%

SQL>
```

Comment: Hii Littlefoot, Tried with regexp_replace(-,-,-) also and it is not compiling, telling it as an error. I actually need to modify data in my column 'ALIAS' where need to remove non numeric values or remove particular string like '+145' from a column data like THE_THIRD_SPARTAN_VIP +1452600165

Comment: "Not compiling" is difficult to debug. Please, post copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session (edit the initial message you wrote) so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded. Also, specify which Oracle database EXACTLY you use (e.g. 11.2, 8.1.7, whatever).